# Displaying all users in Discord channel

Tags: javascript, discord

Right now I am working on a Discord bot and am attempting to list all users that are currently connected to the "general" voice channel.

My main issue right now is that my code is able to realize the number of people in the voice channel, but all of the "member" objects are undefined. This is both the console outputs and code. I have searched everywhere and can't seem to find anything.

**This is the output from the console, the three "undefined" logs are the current users in the voice channel:**

[image]

**This is the code I have written:**

[image]

For convience, this is also the code...

```
var chan = bot.channels['363589387411259396'];
var mems = chan.members;
for (var x in mems) {
  console.log(x.userID);
}
return 'ANYTHING';
```

Any inputs helps, thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide the link to API?

Comment: Of course.
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client <-- this is the Client object documentation

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel <-- this is the Channel object documentation

Comment: [members](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members) is a `Collection<Snowflake, GuildMember>` which extends [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) so you should be able to iterate through the key values like this 
`for (let [snowflake, guildMember] of mems)
{
  console.log('snowflake: ' + snowflake);
  console.log('id: ' + guildMember.id);
  console.log('user id: ' + guildMember.user.id);
}`

Comment: BTW i don't see any [userID](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/search?q=userID) property in `search` not sure where you got that from. All the `GuildMember` properties and methods are available [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)

Comment: I see. I'll also test that out, thanks!

Comment: What is 'bot'? You have bot.channels but I don't see bot ever being defined? I'm trying to figure out the same thing you are.

Answer (score 4):

`Guild.members` returns a `Collection<Snowflake, GuildMember>` object, where `Snowflake` is the `GuildMember`'s ID.

**Your main issue is this:**
`userID` property does not exist. What you should be looking for is `GuildMember.id` or simply printing out the `Snowflake`.
(Since it does not exist, printing out `GuildMember.userID` would result in printing out `undefined`)

Also, you can do your loop as what Venkata mentioned in the comments.